# Composite WPF and AvalonDock

Tags: wpf, prism-2, avalondock

Has anybody tried PRISM and AvalonDock (latest release with DocumentSource property) together? I already had a look at http://www.youdev.net/post/2009/07/17/AvalonDock-Documents.aspx but it just briefs on how to use documentsource property. Please help, if anybody has tried this.

I Would like to know

1.How to associate DocumentSource Property with different regions?

2.Can we assign only a collection of DocumentContent to  DocumentSource property? What about DockableContent?

Thanks & regards, Vishal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch this blog...

http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2010/07/04/prism-and-wpf-custom-tab-region-adapter.aspx
http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2010/07/04/wpf-and-prism-tab-region-adapter-part-02.aspx

Note the comment by the blogger at the bottom...prj coming shortly...